# Why are default custom metrics not showing up when adding a metric to my graph?

Tags: c#, appinsights, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm new to metrics and I'm trying to create a graph that will show the number of successful and failed calls to change feed functions. When I try to select the metrics for my graph, they don't appear under the Custom heading. I am trying to use the default created metrics and I do see them for other applications, as shown below.

[image]

I did find that if I query for the Membership metrics, I do see that they are created (see below).

[image: Query of Membership custom metrics]

Also, if I go into the Advance Editor and add the metrics manually, they do appear as expected in the graph.
So, I'm not sure why they don't appear in the list when adding a metric to my graph. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally there must be custom logic inside the application to log the metric. Perhaps, it exists in Consumer repo code but not in your application.

Comment: Hi Karthik. There is no reference to telemetry.Track..... anything in the code. That's the part that's confusing me.

Comment: I've passed this on internally to our metrics expert.  If it works in advanced mode, but you don't see it as an option in the UX, that usually implies 1 of 2 things: (1) the metrics metadata hasn't updated recently, so it doesn't know there's new fields to show as options (if you open the full metrics explorer outside workbooks do you see them?) or (2) you're using more than one resource in the workbook, so it is only showing the available metrics for the first resource?

Comment: Hi John. No, I don't see them in the metrics explorer either. Thank you for the asisst!

Comment: are you creating them as metrics via explicit `trackMetric` calls or are they metric/measurement values that go along with other events like `trackEvent` ?  in customMeasurement fields?  i can never remember if there's a difference there, but will reach out to the metrics team and see if they can answer?

Answer (score 1):

How many metrics do you have?  The UI will only suggest up to 1000 metric names.  After that, you need to input it manually.

The other limit that you might be running into is all of your metric names need to fit within a 64kb utf-8 string.  See [this doc](https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview?branch=pr-en-us-219712#quotas-and-limits) for details.

Once you hit either of these limits, your metrics will still work, you just won't receive hints or autocomplete for new metrics that are created after the limit is reached.  The limits will be reevaulated once a day or so, so if you reduce the number of metrics or the length of their names, new metrics should start showing up in hints in about a day.